# Take modulus of a byte String

Tags: c++, c, hash, modulus

I have a 128 bit number stored like this...

```
unsigned char upperHalf [8];
unsigned char lowerHalf [8];
```

Where the upperHalf is the upper 8 bytes of the number (In Big Endian Format)
And the lower half is the lower 8 bytes of the number (In Big Endian format)

The big restriction is that I can not use an unsigned long long to fit the 128 bits...

```
sizeof(unsigned long long ) returns 8.
```

I need to modulo this 128 bit number with a 64 bit number.

I was wondering if was there an efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no.

You would need to write your own function to do the modulus properly (unless you can assume it will always be a power of 2, which would allow you to just do shifts).  Or you can use a Big Integer library (e.g. https://mattmccutchen.net/bigint/).